# Node.js global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I asked here:
*[Does Node.js require inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348685/node-js-require-inheritance)*

And I was told that I can set variables to the global scope by leaving out the variable.

This does not work for me.

That is, the following does not make the `_` available on required files.

```
_ = require('underscore');
```

I can set with Express.js's `app.set` and have it available elsewhere though.

Is that how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Where do you have the above line?

Comment: I think you should not start a new question if the answer to your previous question does not work. Rather add a comment there and remove the accepted tag.

Comment: @alienhard but it's old, nobody's going to see it.

Comment: Just editing it makes it appear in the currently active questions list.

Comment: Use `exports`. It's much much better.

Comment: Maybe it does not work because you have "use strict"; on the top of your file. It works like that for me.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You can use [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) like so:

```
global._ = require('underscore')
```

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more information please? Is this part of javascript or part of node? Is it a good pattern to follow? As in should I do this or should I use express set? Thanks

Comment: The previous comment is incorrect. In the browser, `window` is the global object. `document` is a property of `window`.

Comment: This is NOT a good pattern to follow.  Don't do this.  The convention of using 'require' to decouple modules is well thought out.  You shouldn't violate it without a darn good reason.  See my response below.

Comment: Globals are generally to be avoided, but if you really want to use them.
The 3 statements below are all equivalent and will assign a var to the global scope:
GLOBAL._ = require('underscore');
global._ = require('underscore');
_ = require('underscore');

Comment: When you're project starts getting a little bigger this will become a nightmare to maintain. Please take a look at my approach.

Comment: `GLOBAL` is deprecated; use `global` instead.

Comment: Yeah 'global' is like the global 'window' object in the browser

Answer (score 221):

In Node.js, you can set global variables via the "global" or "GLOBAL" object:

```
GLOBAL._ = require('underscore'); // But you "shouldn't" do this! (see note below)
```

or more usefully...

```
GLOBAL.window = GLOBAL;  // Like in the browser
```

From the Node.js source, you can see that these are aliased to each other:

```
node-v0.6.6/src/node.js:
28:     global = this;
128:    global.GLOBAL = global;
```

In the code above, "this" is the global context. With the [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) module system (which Node.js uses), the "this" object inside of a module (i.e., "your code") is *not* the global context.  For proof of this, see below where I spew the "this" object and then the giant "GLOBAL" object.

```
console.log("\nTHIS:");
console.log(this);
console.log("\nGLOBAL:");
console.log(global);

/* Outputs ...

THIS:
{}

GLOBAL:
{ ArrayBuffer: [Function: ArrayBuffer],
  Int8Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
  Uint8Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
  Int16Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2 },
  Uint16Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2 },
  Int32Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
  Uint32Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
  Float32Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
  Float64Array: { [Function] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 8 },
  DataView: [Function: DataView],
  global: [Circular],
  process:
   { EventEmitter: [Function: EventEmitter],
     title: 'node',
     assert: [Function],
     version: 'v0.6.5',
     _tickCallback: [Function],
     moduleLoadList:
      [ 'Binding evals',
        'Binding natives',
        'NativeModule events',
        'NativeModule buffer',
        'Binding buffer',
        'NativeModule assert',
        'NativeModule util',
        'NativeModule path',
        'NativeModule module',
        'NativeModule fs',
        'Binding fs',
        'Binding constants',
        'NativeModule stream',
        'NativeModule console',
        'Binding tty_wrap',
        'NativeModule tty',
        'NativeModule net',
        'NativeModule timers',
        'Binding timer_wrap',
        'NativeModule _linklist' ],
     versions:
      { node: '0.6.5',
        v8: '3.6.6.11',
        ares: '1.7.5-DEV',
        uv: '0.6',
        openssl: '0.9.8n' },
     nextTick: [Function],
     stdout: [Getter],
     arch: 'x64',
     stderr: [Getter],
     platform: 'darwin',
     argv: [ 'node', '/workspace/zd/zgap/darwin-js/index.js' ],
     stdin: [Getter],
     env:
      { TERM_PROGRAM: 'iTerm.app',
        'COM_GOOGLE_CHROME_FRAMEWORK_SERVICE_PROCESS/USERS/DDOPSON/LIBRARY/APPLICATION_SUPPORT/GOOGLE/CHROME_SOCKET': '/tmp/launch-nNl1vo/ServiceProcessSocket',
        TERM: 'xterm',
        SHELL: '/bin/bash',
        TMPDIR: '/var/folders/2h/2hQmtmXlFT4yVGtr5DBpdl9LAiQ/-Tmp-/',
        Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render: '/tmp/launch-9Ga0PT/Render',
        USER: 'ddopson',
        COMMAND_MODE: 'unix2003',
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/tmp/launch-sD905b/Listeners',
        __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: '0x12D732E7:0:0',
        PATH: '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/bin:/usr/X11/bin',
        PWD: '/workspace/zd/zgap/darwin-js',
        LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8',
        ITERM_PROFILE: 'Default',
        SHLVL: '1',
        COLORFGBG: '7;0',
        HOME: '/Users/ddopson',
        ITERM_SESSION_ID: 'w0t0p0',
        LOGNAME: 'ddopson',
        DISPLAY: '/tmp/launch-l9RQXI/org.x:0',
        OLDPWD: '/workspace/zd/zgap/darwin-js/external',
        _: './index.js' },
     openStdin: [Function],
     exit: [Function],
     pid: 10321,
     features:
      { debug: false,
        uv: true,
        ipv6: true,
        tls_npn: false,
        tls_sni: true,
        tls: true },
     kill: [Function],
     execPath: '/usr/local/bin/node',
     addListener: [Function],
     _needTickCallback: [Function],
     on: [Function],
     removeListener: [Function],
     reallyExit: [Function],
     chdir: [Function],
     debug: [Function],
     error: [Function],
     cwd: [Function],
     watchFile: [Function],
     umask: [Function],
     getuid: [Function],
     unwatchFile: [Function],
     mixin: [Function],
     setuid: [Function],
     setgid: [Function],
     createChildProcess: [Function],
     getgid: [Function],
     inherits: [Function],
     _kill: [Function],
     _byteLength: [Function],
     mainModule:
      { id: '.',
        exports: {},
        parent: null,
        filename: '/workspace/zd/zgap/darwin-js/index.js',
        loaded: false,
        exited: false,
        children: [],
        paths: [Object] },
     _debugProcess: [Function],
     dlopen: [Function],
     uptime: [Function],
     memoryUsage: [Function],
     uvCounters: [Function],
     binding: [Function] },
  GLOBAL: [Circular],
  root: [Circular],
  Buffer:
   { [Function: Buffer]
     poolSize: 8192,
     isBuffer: [Function: isBuffer],
     byteLength: [Function],
     _charsWritten: 8 },
  setTimeout: [Function],
  setInterval: [Function],
  clearTimeout: [Function],
  clearInterval: [Function],
  console: [Getter],
  window: [Circular],
  navigator: {} }
*/
```

** Note: regarding setting "GLOBAL._", in general you should just do `var _ = require('underscore');`. Yes, you do that in every single file that uses Underscore.js, just like how in Java you do `import com.foo.bar;`. This makes it easier to figure out what your code is doing because the linkages between files are 'explicit'. It is mildly annoying, but a good thing.  .... That's the preaching.

There is an exception to every rule.  I have had precisely exactly *one* instance where I needed to set "GLOBAL._".  I was creating a system for defining "configuration" files which were basically JSON, but were "written in JavaScript" to allow a bit more flexibility.  Such configuration files had no 'require' statements, but I wanted them to have access to Underscore.js (the *entire* system was predicated on Underscore.js and Underscore.js templates), so before evaluating the "configuration", I would set "GLOBAL._".  So yeah, for every rule, there's an exception somewhere.  But you had better have a darn good reason and not just "I get tired of typing 'require', so I want to break with the convention".

Comment: What are the downfalls of using GLOBAL? Why do I need a darn good reason? The bottom line is that my app works, right?

Comment: ultimately, yes, if you ship, that's all that counts.  However, certain practices are known as "best practices" and following them typically increases your odds of shipping and / or being able to maintain what you have built.  The importance of following "good practice" increases with the size of the project and it's longevity.  I've built all kinds of nasty hacks into short-lived projects that were write-once, read-never (and "single-developer").  In a bigger project, that sort of corner cutting ends up costing you project momentum.

Comment: Specifically, with GLOBAL, the issue is one of readability.  If your program promiscuously uses global variables, it means that in order to understand the code, I must understand the dynamic runtime state of the entire app.  This is why programmers are leery of globals.  I'm sure there's dozens of ways to use them effectively, but we've mostly just seen them abused by junior programmers to the ill of the product.

Comment: Why can't you just put your configs in a regular `.js` file and call `require` before exporting the configs?

Comment: That's also a good question. Can't you just `var config = require('config.js');` and export the "written in JS" object?

Comment: @Dave Dopson : I support the idea of putting config values into config.js and use `require('config.js')` ! It'll make searching all configs easier.

Comment: @DaveDopson What about a scenario where you're separating your web app logic into separate .js files, and within those files, you need to reference centralized variables/functions/modules? You'd use global in this scenario, right?

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti: Nope, you have an abstraction which proxies the desired exports from the individual modules of some component and exposes them all through one module.  With that way, a component which each consists of a dozen or more files can be used by require'ing a single file, and without polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti:  In my current project, I have a `config` unit which used to read a config from JSON, but now does it from MySQL.  This design change required changing only one file, the `config.js`.

I also have some utility functions (things which underscore doesn't quite do the way I wanted), in a `util.js`

Comment: About this specific use-case you mention that was the *"precisely exactly ONE instance"* where you needed `GLOBAL`, if it was generated code, couldn't you anyway have used `var _ = require('_')` at the top? I'm not saying there's a way around every case where you'd need `GLOBAL`, but this case could maybe have had the workaround (even if for the sake of whoever was reading the generated template code or whatever).

Comment: The case I used it was one where I had to define a db connection and do about 5 lines of setup. I get this in theory but that was 5 lines of code in essentially every JS lib. What is the real disadvantage to doing this? Is it just accidentally overriding core JS stuff?

Comment: @Jackie - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern. if what you are doing maps to the Singleton pattern, then it might make sense. DB connections can be singletons when: 1) setup is expensive, 2) you only want the connection to be set up once, 3) the connection object is long-lived and won`t enter a failed state in the event of network hiccups, 4) the connection object is thread-safe / able to be shared by many different callers.

Comment: You're going to pollute name space with this and it WILL become a maintenance nightmare, I've seen it many times. Look at my approach.

Comment: Is it only me to think "i get tired of typing 'require' so I want to break with convention" is damn good reason?

Comment: This looks horrible.

Comment: I don't know when but `GLOBAL` has apparently been deprecated in favor of `global`. I just got this warning in node 7.3.0 `DeprecationWarning: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global'`

Comment: For node modules this is quite okay, but what about all the files containing the classes of your own application? To require them you need to wire them to their paths, which becomes a nightmare. Not only to figure out the current releative path but also when refactoring and hence paths do change.

Comment: mention that `GLOBAL` variable is deprecated and you have to use `global`

Answer (score 81):

The other solutions that use the GLOBAL keyword are a nightmare to maintain/readability (+namespace pollution and bugs) when the project gets bigger. I've seen this mistake many times and had the hassle of fixing it.

Use a JavaScript file and then use module exports.

**Example:**

#### File *globals.js*

```
var Globals = {
    'domain':'www.MrGlobal.com';
}

module.exports = Globals;
```

Then if you want to use these, use *require*.

```
var globals = require('globals'); // << globals.js path
globals.domain // << Domain.
```

Comment: I surely don't love Unicorns but like your approach. Thanks.

Comment: What about changing `globals.domain` though?

Comment: @Fizzix my suggestion here would be to use an observer pattern if you really need to change globals; in theory you should not be changing globals.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns thanks for replying. I'll look into alternatives such as 'express-session' since I mainly need it for storing the logged in user data.

Comment: While this in my opinion is a better approach, it does not create globals and does not answer the question asked. It's an alternative approach and I'd always encourage those, however the sheer bullish cocky-ness of statements like "This is the only correct answer on this thread" simply don't belong here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @Thor84no I changed it for you.

Comment: This may be a better approach, but if you’re trying to run externally-authored scripts which rely on something being in the global namespace, this doesn’t help you. IOW, this doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: "global" itself is just a module, pre-required for you on every file

Comment: @OliverDixon - similar to @Fizzix, I am in a situation where I need to be able to access *and update* global variables from multiple modules, can u pls elaborate on how `observer pattern` would be implemented in a node/express environment?  i have [a question with more context here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185112/how-to-define-all-socket-io-io-onconnection-logic-outside-of-app-js-in-a-sep)

Comment: @user1063287 you can use ```export let``` then a setter function inside the file.

Answer (score 13):

Use a global namespace like `global.MYAPI = {}`:

```
global.MYAPI._ = require('underscore')
```

---

All other posters talk about the bad pattern involved. So leaving that discussion aside, the best way to have a variable defined globally (OP's question) is through namespaces.

Tip: *[Development Using Namespaces](http://thanpol.as/javascript/development-using-namespaces)*

Comment: That's what `require` is for! It's ok to use namespaces, but don't go all `global.foo = global.foo || {}` on all files, or something. Require the file that defines the namespace. Do it for the children.

Comment: @camilo-martin Hi, 1) By defining global.MYAPI._ you don't need define it in all files,  That's the reason of being global. 2) This nothing has to be with the children. Even if all says that is bad pattern, It's depends of the programmer and the given situation how he use this capabiltiy of the language.

Comment: Yes, but let's say you declare some of the functionality of a namespace in a separate file. Then you're requiring a file to use the object, which is backwards and goes against CommonJS and CommonSense, too. If you're going to require stuff, have the user code require the namespace and not be required by the namespace. Note I'm not saying anything *against* namespaces, just that there's conventions on who calls who for a reason. And in client-side you don't have what node has; see the link you mention is doing things in a certain way (through global) because it's about the browser and not node.

Comment: Sadly the URL you posted only works if you leave out the trailing slash ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can just use the global object.

```
var X = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
global.x = X;

console.log(x);
//['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree that using the global/GLOBAL namespace for setting anything global is bad practice and don't use it at all in theory (*in theory* being the operative word). However (yes, the operative) I do use it for setting custom Error classes:

```
// Some global/configuration file that gets called in initialisation

global.MyError = [Function of MyError];
```

Yes, it is taboo here, but if your site/project uses custom errors throughout the place, you would basically need to define it everywhere, or at least somewhere to:

1. Define the Error class in the first place
2. In the script where you're throwing it
3. In the script where you're catching it

Defining my custom errors in the global namespace saves me the hassle of *require*'ing my customer error library. Imaging throwing a custom error where that custom error is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to access **strings** globally, I recommend using `dotenv`:

Install with:

```
npm i dotenv
```

Then create the file `.env` in the project's root directory and set all of the variables you want to be global, for example:

```
DB_HOST='localhost'
DB_DATABASE='my_database'
DB_USER='my_user'
DB_PASSWORD='my_password'

ADMIN_EMAIL='foo@bar.baz'
CITY='Some city'
# ... etc
```

You can even set these variables by the command line when starting the server like this:

```
NODE_ENV=dev PORT=5000 npm run start-dev
```

Also, if you use git, you likely want to add `.env` to your `.gitignore` to make sure you don't accidentally commit sensitive information.

Then just include the following at the beginning of your `server.js` file (or whatever the first file to be executed is)

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

To use these variables anywhere in your code, just use `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`.

For example:

```js
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}.`)
})
```

**Note**: I understand this doesn't directly answer the question since it is about storing strings globally instead of Underscore.js, but I thought I would include it for completeness.