# Node.js express 3

Tags: node.js, express

I want to put the fallowing in a helper but i get and require it in my app.js. My current error is app is not defined. I am new to node.js so if this is a easy one dont be to hard on me.

```
app.locals.use({flashMessages: function(req, res) {
var html = ""
  , flash  = req.flash();
['error', 'info'].forEach(function(type) {
  if(flash[type]) {
    flash[type].forEach(function(message) {
      html += "<div class='alert " + type + "'>" + message + "</div>";
    });
  }
});
return html; }});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should either convert this to a function that accepts an app parameter, or you could put app into GLOBAL. See [node.js global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

Comment: that was not clear at all. I have no understanding of how to do or what to do with what you have said.

Comment: @Vartan Arabyan your problem is that when you move this code to a new file you are losing the reference to app. So what I'm saying is that you can either convert this code into a function that you could call in a context where app is known, or you could put app into a global variable, so that in the context of your new file you could still access app

Comment: can you please give me an example of making it a function.

Comment: Well just surround your code with function my_code() {<your_code>};,place that function in the same file where app is defined and call the function (my_code();) after you define app.

Comment: of course, that's very bad practice, but the most straight forward.