# Is it possible to declare global variables in Node/Express 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have multiple routes that need to access a database, for development I use a local database, and obviously production I use a hosted database

The only problem is every time I go to push a release I have to go through each route manually changing the database link

e.g.

`var mongodb = require('mongojs').connect('urlhere', ['Collection']);`

It would be nice if I could declare a variable in `app.js` like

`app.set('mongoDBAddress', 'urlhere');`

then in each file do something like 
`var mongodb = require('mongojs').connect(app.get('mongoDBAddress'), ['Collection']);`

Does anybody know if this is achievable I've been messing around with it for about an hour googling and trying to include different things but I have no luck. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that
>   in browsers if you're in the global scope `var something` will define a
>   global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not
>   the global scope; `var something` inside a Node module will be **local to
>   that module**.

You have to think a bit differently. Instead of creating a global object, create your modules so they take an `app` instance, for example:

```
// add.js
module.exports = function(app) { // requires an `app`
  return function add(x, y) { // the actual function to export
    app.log(x + y) // use dependency
  }
}

// index.js
var app = {log: console.log.bind(console)}
var add = require('./add.js')(app) // pass `app` as a dependency

add(1, 2)
//^ will log `3` to the console
```

This is the convention in Express, and other libraries. `app` is in your main file (ie. `index.js`), and the modules you require have an `app` parameter.

You can add a global variable to `GLOBAL`, see this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables), although this is probably considered bad practice.

Comment: No. There is a global scope, only it's not the module's toplevel scope. Your first sentence sounds as if every module had its own *global* scope, which is not true.

Comment: @Bergi: yeah... I'll just leave the quote from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

We have two methods in node.js to share variables within modules.

1. global
2. module.export

But your problem seems to be different, what I got is you want to connect your application to different  databases without changing code. What you need to do is use **command line params**

[For more ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)

**server.js**

```
var connectTo = {
    dev : "url1"
    production : "url2"
}

var mongodb = require('mongojs').connect(connectTo[process.argv[2]], ['Collection']);
```

**Run your server.js as**

```
node server.js dev
// for connecting to development database
```

or

```
node server.js production
// for connecting to prodiction database
```

**To share connection across diffrent modules**

```
//Method 1
global.mongodb = require('mongojs').connect(connectTo[process.argv[2]], ['Collection']);

//Method 2
exports.mongodb = require('mongojs').connect(connectTo[process.argv[2]], ['Collection']);

exports.getMongoDBAddress = function() {
    return connectTo[process.argv[2]]
}
```