# How to add global variables used by all tests in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, testing, code-reuse, base-class, code-duplication

I could not find how to remove code duplication in Javascript (basically what I would achieve in Java with base classes).

The concrete example is (at least) the following code, which is common to all spec files (and potentially page objects, since I am testing with that pattern in protractor):

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;
```

Can I do something to have *expect* available everywhere?
I tried in the protractor configuration to load a file with that before the specs:

```
specs: [
  'e2e/helpers/commonDefinitions.js',
  'e2e/**/*.spec.js'
]
```

or use *beforeLaunch* or *onPrepare* (but want a function, not sure how to expose vars that way), but without success.

However, I would prefer a generic Javascript approach to this kind of code reuse.

Is there any good way to avoid repeating this kind of common code everywhere, especially in tests (mocha, karma, protractor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to place that code in a separate file:

`assert-styles.js`

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should;

module.exports = {
  expect: expect,
  should: should
};
```

and then import it to your other test files:

`test1.js`

```
var assertStyles = require('./assert-styles');
var expect = assertStyles.expect;
var should = assertStyles.should;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good if eventually I need only expect, as is the case here.
But would there be a way to export multiple vars, making really a file exposing many modules needed by others?
Because if I do a require per file/module, I will gain very little reusability :)

Comment: @cowst definitely, just export and object `module.exports = {expect: expect, assert: assert};` and then require like so, `var common = require('./common'); var expect common.expect; var assert = common.assert;`

Comment: Ok, this way is convenient to keep all helper libs in one place, and in cases like the above, where we use 4 lines to get to the 1 var we need.

If we would just declare directly 1 needed var per line, we would rewrite each line in the files using them, so instead of saving code we would write one line extra everywhere (the require) :D

I hoped for something more convenient, were injecting one file (written in the right way) would provide you already the visibility of the vars.

Anyway, please edit your answer so I can mark it as "best we can do" for my needs :)

Comment: please edit your answer so I can mark it as "best we can do" for my needs :)

Comment: @cowst I don't think there's a good way around it. You can use the `GLOBAL` object but it's considered bad practice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables