# Unable to initialize JavaScript Class to name keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
        var NameOne = function (firstName, lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        NameOne.prototype.getName=function(){
            console.log(this.firstName+' '+this.lastName);
        }
        var name = new NameOne('Prashant','Jain');
        name.getName();
```

**ERROR**

> Uncaught TypeError: name.getName is not a function

getting above error in browsers if naming object as name and running on browsers. It is working fine on nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

`window.name` is a getter/setter style property in browsers which converts everything to *String* (to be the *name* of the *Window*)

Therefore `var`ing it does not work as you expect and you end up with

```
name; // "[object Object]"
```

You will need to either

- Choose a different identifier to avoid this conflict
- Work in a scope other than the global scope so `var` will work for `name`

Answer (score 2):

This is because in javascript name is in-built property. so when you call `name.getName()` it will be actually called on global window object as below
`window.name.getName()` which will throw an error. You need to choose different identifier other than 'name' to work it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In a browser, the global scope refers to the `window` object, which has a property called `name`.

If you read about scoping in JavaScript, for example in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), you'll find this information (at the bottom of the page):

> Your global variables (or functions) can overwrite window variables (or functions).
>   Any function, including the window object, can overwrite your global variables and functions.

That means that, if you try to define any variable or function which already exists as a member of the global `window` object, you will not be able to do it. When you try to access them, you'll be accessing the global `window` object member.

You can check that, after creating your object `name === window.name` yields true, which means that it's not your object, but the `window.name` property.

You can also check that whenever you create a var in the global scope, it's created as a member of window. i.e.

```
var x = 22;
window.hasOwnProperty('x'); // returns true
console.log(window.x); // you'll see 22 in your console
```

To get rid of this problem you need to scope your variable. JavaScript only creates new scopes in function's bodies. So, one way to create your own scope it's to use the "self executing anonymous function" pattern, which looks like this:

```
(function(){ 
   /* new scope: variables are created here without window global object
   *  interference. You can still access globlas using window.globalName */ 
})();
```

You can read an interesting article on this pattern [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

In node.js there is no `name` in the global scope, thus you don't have that problem. There is a great explanation of what is in node.js global scope in [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables#answer-9590297).