# How to define mongoDB database connection variable globally

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have worked to **node js + mysql**. but now i am going to **node js + mongoDB**
I am in need to connect database and make a variable for globally use.
I am very much confused how we can define variable for globally use.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
    console.log('Connection established to', url);

    // do some work here with the database.


    db.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

Comment: how can i make db for globally use?? this is in function..

Comment: @iam check out the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-to-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-nodejs-webapp)