# how to define user defined constant globally in nodejs

Tags: node.js

1. Here, my question is, we use define function in php to define the
   contant globally but how can i achive same thing in nodejs

   in php: 
    define(nameofthecontant, value);
    in nodejs how to?

   ```
     var dataBaseInfo = result.databaseInfo; 
       // global.DB_HOST = dataBaseInfo['DB_HOST'];             
        for(var keys in dataBaseInfo) {
            global.keys = dataBaseInfo[keys];  

        }
   ```

   i have data in result.databaseInfo from database xml file and m trying to create global contant using for loop, its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

Comment: Also, it should probably be `GLOBAL.keys = GLOBAL.keys || [];` then `GLOBAL.keys.push( dataBaseInfo[keys] )`

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can define a variable in the global namespace:

```
global.nameofthecontant = value
```

This is something that you don't want to do in node.js though. Your question possibly is a duplicate of this question: [node.js global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

Comment: yes, one more doubt i have, just i wll edit the question check it

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from this:

```
global.keys = dataBaseInfo[keys];
```

to this:

```
global[keys] = dataBaseInfo[keys];
```

When you want to access or assign a property and the property name is in a variable, you use the `obj[variableName]` syntax.

You could also use Object.assign here if you just want to copy a bunch of properties from one object to another:

```
Object.assign(global, databaseInfo);
```

---

As others have said, it is usually frowned upon to use globals in this way in node.js.  Instead, you would typically expose these constants in a module and then just require in the module in any other module that wants to access the constants.  This makes your code more modular and makes each module more self-contained.

Comment: its working but not what i was excepting, i wanted to use directly DB_HOST like constant , its working in single assignment explame: global.DB_HOST = localhost, once u assigned ln this way, then i can use it direclty, i need in looping to declare constant. is it possible?

Comment: @UmakantMane - You're going the wrong way for node.js development.  Globals are evil.  That is not how you should design code in node.js.  Create a module with the globals in it, require in that constant and reference them as `someModule.someConstant`.  Or, use destructing assignment to assign them from the module to local variables in your module which you can then use like globals, but they won't actually be evil globals.

Comment: @UmakantMane - See what I added to my prior comment about destructing assignment as an option too.