# Error with Discord bot change prefix command (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, command, prefix, discord

I have an issue which I really don't know how to solve. When I try to implement the change prefix command in my code I get an error when I want to use it. First the code was all in 1 file and it worked fine, but I splitted the file so that the commands have each a different file. This is where the code didn't work anymore. I'm sure it's because I'm not good in javascript but please help me!

This is the main file:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const newUsers = [];
const fs = require("fs")

// Error en warning berichten.
client.on("error", (e) => console.error(e));
client.on("warn", (e) => console.warn(e));


// This loop reads the /events/ folder and attaches each event file to the appropriate event.
fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    let eventFunction = require(`./events/${file}`);
    let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    // super-secret recipe to call events with all their proper arguments *after* the `client` var.
    client.on(eventName, (...args) => eventFunction.run(client, ...args));
  });
});

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;

  // This is the best way to define args. Trust me.
  const args = message.content.split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().slice(config.prefix.length).toLowerCase();

  // The list of if/else is replaced with those simple 2 lines:
  try {
    let commandFile = require(`./commands/${command}.js`);
    commandFile.run(client, message, args);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  if(!args || args.size < 1) return message.reply("Must provide a command name to reload.");
  // the path is relative to the *current folder*, so just ./filename.js
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./${args[0]}.js`)];
  message.reply(`The command ${args[0]} has been reloaded`);
};

client.login(config.token);
```

This is the prefix file:

```html
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  const modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Discord Admin");
  if (!modRole) 
    return console.log("The Discord Admin role does not exist.");

  if (!message.member.roles.has(modRole.id))
    return message.reply("You can't use this command.");

   // Verandert de prefix van de command (vb. "!prefix +" ontvangt de "+" dus word het "+prefix").
      let newPrefix = message.content.split(" ").slice(1, 2)[0];
      // Verandert de configuratie in memory
      config.prefix = newPrefix;
      // Slaat het bestand op.
      fs.writeFile("./config.json", JSON.stringify(config), (err) => console.error);
}
```

And in the config file is: "prefix":"!"

I really tried a lot of things but I keep this error in node.js:

> ReferenceError: config is not defined
>       at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\fleur\Desktop\botdiscord\commands\prefix.js:12:7)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to require `config` in `commands\prefix.js`

If you want to have a global variable in node.js you have to assign it to the global scope.

See this article [node.js global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

Comment: I need to have the config.json file in this folder http://prntscr.com/g0xob0
Is there a way that I can do the require command even though its not in the command folder?

Comment: You can require it with it's relative path: `const config = require('../config.json')`