# Share randomly generated variable across .js and .ejs files with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am generating a random number inside a javascript file that I need to pass through to an .ejs file. Obivously I can't just reproduce it there because it is random.

I am working with these files: app.js, game.js and game.ejs. I need to use the variable in both game files.

This is the variable I need to be shared

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
```

I already tried passing the variable through my app.js to the game.ejs which worked. I can still not work with it in my game.js though.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you storing it in a database ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

make this varibale global like

```
global.num = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
```

now use it at any place inside your environment.

> Global varibales must be handled with care as it pollutes

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. In which file would I define this variable?

Comment: you can maintain a separate file for global variables or else you can just use it anywhere. But be cautious with naming as you may overwrite the value by mistake at other place

Comment: @SaikatHajra will it also accessible on frontend as opp wants to use in `game.ejs` ??

Comment: you can only access by rendering