# Sailsjs - What is the proper way to add new modules for use with the Sails framework?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

What is the proper way of adding a new Module in Sailsjs? 
I understand I can just "npm install" a new module and "require" it in the pages I want to use it - but I believe there is a better way of doing that without having to repeatedly "require" the new module everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the proper way of adding modules within your code. Your code becomes easier to maintain when you explicitly use `require()`, where you need it.

However, you can also make a module globally available. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590297/1640425) to find out how to do this and why you shouldn't be doing this.