# How to use should.js as global variable:

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, mocha.js, should.js

I am trying to write some unit test that using mocha and should.js since I would like to keep format for each of my unit test the same and each unit test require should.js to verify proerpty of object. How can I make it as globally variable so I do not need to require should.js on each test file so far I have tried

```
global.should = require('should');
describe('try gloabl'), () => {
  it('should work'), () => {
    let user = { name: 'test'};
    global.should(user).have.property('name', 'test');
  });
});
#error, global.should is not a function
```

and if i use this. it works

```
const should = require('should');
should = require('should');
describe('try gloabl'), () => {
  it('should work'), () => {
    let user = { name: 'test'};
    global.should(user).have.property('name', 'test');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `I'm tired of writing "require"` is the **worst** reason to use the GLOBAL variable. There is a reason that using `require` is the conventional way of doing things, and it is not different from any other language where you have to `import` or type `using` in each and every file. It just makes it easier to understand what the code is doing later on.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590297/4423258) for further explanation.

Now, that said, when requiring `should`, the module actually attaches itself to the GLOBAL variable, and makes `describe`, `it` and `should` accessible methods.

**index.js**

```
require('should');

describe('try global', () => {
    it('should work with global', () => {
        let user = { name: 'test' };
        global.should(user).have.property('name', 'test');
    });
    it('should work without global', () => {
        let user = { name: 'test' };
        should(user).have.property('name', 'test');
    });
});

//////
mocha ./index.js

try global
    √ should work with global
    √ should work without global


2 passing (11ms)
```

I fixed the typos in your code (eg. Removing the extra `)` from `describe` and `it` function), and this code works just fine when running with `mocha ./index.js`. Make sure you have install `mocha` with `npm i -g mocha` to make the module available in the CLI.